# Auto input to make multiple chooses of a script in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, echo, dockerfile

I have a shell script like blow, and I want to execute it in a `Dockerfle` and make auto choose using `echo -e`:

```
1. Which application you'd select:
    1) nginx
    2) squid
    3) hproxy
  Please enter a number (Default: 1): 2

  You choose = squid

2. Please enter password for squid (Default: xxxxxxxx): yyyyyyyy

  password = yyyyyyyy

3. Please enter a port for squid [1-65535] (Default: 443): 3128
  port = 3128

4. ....
```

This works in a docker shell:

```
echo -e "2\nmypass\n3128\n" | bash install-proxy.sh
```

but can't work in a `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN echo -e "2\nmypass\n\3128\n" | bash install-proxy.sh
```

it seems that the `RUN` command make them in one line so that the first choose accepted wrong select and the later chooses didn't accept any select.

The whole script is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teddysun/shadowsocks_install/master/shadowsocks-all.sh)

Comment: Read your script again - `echo -e` doesn't read input, `read -p` does.

Comment: Yes, the original script use `read -p` to receive values from standard input interactively, that's what I'm trying to avoid, so I used `echo -e`, you can try this `echo -e "mypassword\nmypassword" | passwd root` and would understand what I hope to do.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier for your script to ask for those values (to be read from stdin) only if a known environment variable was *not* set.

That way, your Dockerfile can set `ENV app=xxx` *before* `RUN install-proxy.sh`

If it detects that `app` is set, it would skip the question part, and go directly to the printing "`you chose '$app'`".

That way, you bypass entirely the tricky part of sending stdin content to a script through pipe in a Dockerfile `RUN` step.

Comment: This is a great solution, seems like I'll have to download the script(not write by me) and edit it for my own use.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the script as you suggested so that it can receive values from ENV which I passed in using Dockerfile, and the container is working now.